# MYSQL script comamnd runs successfully but MYSQL still performaning operations in background that i cant see:Explanation Required

Tags: mysql, bash

i had a test database on MySQL and items are stored in different tables, when some users delete some items using application i didn't get deleted from database but we set the items deleted=1 so that application cant access it and it remains in database.

after few month we execute the script which finds the items which has deleted=1 and delete them from table permanently. My Database has 120 GB size and i execute the cleanup.sql script using command "`#mysql -u root -pmypassword testDatabase < cleanup.sql`" and the command took 13 HR to complete.but after 13 hours if i use "`show full processlist;`" in MYSQL i didn't show me any process. but if i use `#iotop` command to see disk usage i can see  MySQL process reading/writing to disk.

```
Total DISK READ: 1218.79 K/s | Total DISK WRITE: 66.91 M/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
30898 be/4 mysql    1218.79 K/s   36.28 M/s  0.00 % 15.70 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --l~e=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
30145 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s    7.43 K/s  0.00 %  0.03 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --l~e=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
30147 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s   32.40 M/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --l~e=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

and if i see database size using:

```
SELECT table_schema "Database Names", sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 /1024 "Data Base Size in GB" FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema ;
```

i can see database reducing after time to time like from 104.194 GB to 103.466 GB and so on.

**My Question is Why i cant see any process running in MYSQL, and how do i make sure my script executed completely other than seeing the disk usage.**

Comment: What engine (`InnoDB` or `MyISAM` or another) are you using for this table? Different engines deploy different I/O strategies that serve for differnet purposes. E.g `InnoDB` with a buffer pool will not immediately flush logical changes to disk, but buffer them. `MyISAM`, for instance doesn't clean up data files but reuses space of deleted rows for future `INSERT`s (because indexes depend on each row's offset in the data file) - until `OPTIMIZE TABLE` or `myisamchk` is used to manually rewrite the data file.

Comment: i checked with this command "SELECT TABLE_NAME, ENGINE FROM information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'testdatabse';" and most of tables shows InnoDB and only 1,2 table shows MYISAM. so cleanup involves tables which mostly has Engine InnoDB. thanks